# Add a link on each span

Tags: html, css

I want to add a text link on each span of the slider below.I tried many things but I cant seem to get it right. The slider works as follows, there are buttons numbered 1 to 4 at the bottom of the slider. Clicking on them causes another pane to slide out.ON each slide I want to add a text link which will direct me to another page.You can check it on my website www.dailycrazydeals.com.

THe HTML:

```
<!-- radio buttons and labels -->
<input id="select-img-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-1" checked/>
<label for="select-img-1" class="cr-label-img-1">1</label>

<input id="select-img-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-2" />
<label for="select-img-2" class="cr-label-img-2">2</label>

<input id="select-img-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-3" />
<label for="select-img-3" class="cr-label-img-3">3</label>

<input id="select-img-4" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-4" />
<label for="select-img-4" class="cr-label-img-4">4</label>

<div class="clr"></div> 

<!-- panels -->
<div class="cr-bgimg">
    <div>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 1 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 2 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 3 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 1</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 2</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 3</span>
        <span>Slice 4 - Image 4</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- titles -->
<div class="cr-titles">
    <h3> 
       <span>Surface Pro 2</span>
        <span>What you've been dreaming of</span>
<div id="xyz_header" onclick="
location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';">
Header </div>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Adventure</span>
        <span>Where the fun begins</span>
 <a class="sliderlink2" href="http://www.yahoo.com">$400</a>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Nature</span>
        <span>Unforgettable eperiences</span>
 <a class="sliderlink3" href="http://www.google.com">$500</a>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <span>Serenity</span>
        <span>When silence touches nature</span>
 <a class="sliderlink4" href="">$600</a>
    </h3>
 </div>

 </section>
```

CSS:

```
.cr-container{
width: 980px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 20px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.cr-container label{
font-style: italic;
width: 245px;
height: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
line-height: 32px;
font-size: 24px;
float:left;
position: relative;
margin-top: 260px;
z-index: 1000;
text-align: center;
}
.cr-container label:before{
content:'';
width: 34px;
height: 34px;
background: rgba(130,195,217,0.9);
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -17px;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
z-index:-1;
}
.cr-container label:after{
width: 1px;
height: 400px;
content: '';
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
position: absolute;
bottom: -20px;
right: 0px;
}
.cr-container label.cr-label-img-4:after{
width: 0px;
}
.cr-container input{
display: none;
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-1,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-2,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-3,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-4{
color: #68abc2;
   }
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-1:before,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-2:before,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-3:before,
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ label.cr-label-img-4:before{
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(104,171,194,0.6);
}
.cr-bgimg{
width: 980px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
.cr-bgimg div{
width: 245px;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.cr-bgimg div span{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: -150px;
z-index: 2;
text-indent: -9000px;
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ .cr-bgimg,
.cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(1){
background-image: url('_assets/img/Surfacepro.png');
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ .cr-bgimg,
.cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(2){
background-image: url('_assets/img/Surfacepro.png');
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ .cr-bgimg,
.cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(3){
background-image: url('_assets/img/Surfacepro.png');
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ .cr-bgimg,
.cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(4){
background-image: url('_assets/img/Surfacepro.png');
}
.cr-bgimg div:nth-child(1) span{
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.cr-bgimg div:nth-child(2) span{
background-position: -245px 0px;
}
.cr-bgimg div:nth-child(3) span{
background-position: -490px 0px;
}
.cr-bgimg div:nth-child(4) span{
background-position: -735px 0px;
}
.cr-container input:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span{
animation: slideOut 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes slideOut{
0%{
    left: 0px;
}
100%{
    left: 245px;
}
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(1),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(2),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(3),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ .cr-bgimg div span:nth-child(4)
{
transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
animation: none;
left: 0px;
z-index: 10;
}
.cr-titles h3{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
top: 0%;
opacity: 0;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.cr-titles h3 span:nth-child(1){
font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
display: block;
letter-spacing: 7px;
margin-right: 550px;
margin-top: 25px;
}
.cr-titles h3 span:nth-child(2){
letter-spacing: 0px;
display: block;
background: rgba(104,171,194,0.9);
font-size: 14px;
padding: 5px;
font-style: italic;
font-family: Cambria, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
margin-top: 170px;
}
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-1:checked ~ .cr-titles h3:nth-child(1),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-2:checked ~ .cr-titles h3:nth-child(2),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-3:checked ~ .cr-titles h3:nth-child(3),
.cr-container input.cr-selector-img-4:checked ~ .cr-titles h3:nth-child(4){
opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.cr-container input{
    display: inline;
    width: 24%;
    margin-top: 350px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}
.cr-container label{
    display: none;
}
}
.cr-titles h3:nth-child(1) { z-index: 10001; }
.cr-titles h3:nth-child(2) { z-index: 10001; }
.cr-titles h3:nth-child(3) { z-index: 10001; }
.cr-titles h3:nth-child(4) { z-index: 10001; }
```

Comment: What's the matter with `<a href=#></a>`?

Comment: <a href=""><span></span></a> this will work

Comment: when I click on the radio button to move to another span,it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is valid

```
<a href="#">some <span class="red">text</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <span><a href="http:\\www.google.com">google</a></span>
        <a href="http:\\www.pluralsight.com"><span>pluralsight</span></a>
```

above both statements are valid and working correctly.